# Convert numbers to non-numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I notice that numeric values like `123456` can be considered as numbers or non-numbers in Excel. Mixing numbers and non-numbers may result in unexpected results of `=` or `XLOOKUP`.

For instance, in the following worksheet, the formula of `D3` is `=ISNUMBER(C3)` and the formula of `D4` is `=ISNUMBER(C4)`. Their values are not the same. Then `=C3=C4` in another cell will return FALSE; `=XLOOKUP(C3,C4,C4)` will return `#N/A`.

[image]

So one solution to avoid such surprises is that I would like to convert all these numeric values from numbers to non-numbers, before applying formulas on them.

Does anyone know if it is possible to undertake this conversion by manual operations (select the range, then...)?

Does anyone know how to achieve this conversion by a subroutine in VBA (select the range, then run the VBA subroutine, then the selected range will be converted)?

Comment: Just edit the formula a little bit. No need for VBA

Comment: @JvdV I know it is doable with `TEXT` or `VALUETOTEXT` function, but we have lots of formulas, I would like to solve the problem from the root and have consistant formats for all the input data. I'm looking for a manual solution and a VBA solution.

Comment: When I use text functions to get numbers then the last thing I do is *1 like this : "=left(c4,2)*1" which makes sure numbers are numbers - at least works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you firstly write numbers in a range, let us say "C:C", formatted as `General`, any such a cell will return `TRUE` when you try `=ISNUMBER(C4)`.
2. If you preliminary format the range as `Text` and **after that** write a number, this will be seen by Excel as a `String` (non-numbers, as you say...) and `=ISNUMBER(C4)` will return `False`.
3. Now, if you will try formatting the range as `Text` **after writing the numbers** these cells will not be changed in a way to make `=ISNUMBER(C4)` returning `FALSE`. In order to do that, you can use `TextToColumns`, as in the next example:

```
Private Sub testTextToCol()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set rng = sh.Range("C:C")
    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)
End Sub
```

It will make the existing `=ISNUMBER(C4)`, initially returning `TRUE`, to return `FALSE`...

Answer (score 0):

Of course you cannot compare apples to oranges, thus strings are not comparable to integers/longs/numbers. Make sure that all you compare are apples.

In a routine this would be s.th. like

```
Option Explicit

Sub changeFormat():

' Declare variables

Dim Number As Variant
Dim check As Boolean

'Converts the format of cells D3 and D4 to "Text"

Range("D3:D4").NumberFormat = "@"

'Assign cell to be evaluated

Number = Range("D3")

Debug.Print Number 'Prints '123'

check = WorksheetFunction.IsText(Trim(Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(4, 3)))

Debug.Print check 'Prints True

'Converts the format of cells D3 and D4 to "Numbers"

Range("D3:D4").NumberFormat = "0.00"

'Compare Cells

If Range("D3").NumberFormat = Range("D4").NumberFormat Then Range("D5").Value = "Same Format"

End Sub
```

Also see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat)

Comment: Could you give a full solution of VBA?

Comment: @SoftTimur done :)

Comment: Did you test `Range("D3:D4").NumberFormat = "@"`? For D3:D4 that are numbers, that statement will not convert them to non-numbers.

Comment: @SoftTimur it runs well on my end.

Comment: It did not work well on my side. Did you use `=ISNUMBER(...)` function to check their return values, did you compare their return values to non-numbers (whose `ISNUMBER` is FALSE) to check?

Comment: @SoftTimur did you trim it? I updated my answer which works well.

Comment: Setting the Numberformat doesn't convert a number into a string. It's just changing how the number is displayed.